# Traducción (a una palabra) de "restraining order"

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

Estoy buscando *una palabra* que estoy seguro se usaba en Venezuela, o quizá más bien era en las traducciones / doblajes de las series de televisión policíacas estadounidenses que veíamos en Venezuela (estoy hablando de hace más de 20 - 25 años).

Recuerdo claramente que cuando aprendí que en inglés se dice "restraining order", me parecía curiosa esa expresión, pues estaba acostumbrado a que era *una palabra* en español, la cual no me viene a la mente / no logro recordar...

Pareciera ser que, o bien es una palabra que ya no se usa y no logro encontrar a nadie que se acuerde de ella, o bien no era una palabra usada en Venezuela (y que más bien es una palabra mexicana, o argentina, o de donde fuera que se hicieran los doblajes para televisión en latinoamérica).

Actualmente, a quien sea que le pregunte, me responden que eso se dice "orden de alejamiento", "medida cautelar", etc.

Answer (score 1):

El término "restraining order" es cercano en inglés a "injunction".

Ambos pueden traducirse como "medida cautelar" y también como "**interdicto**", que tal vez sea la palabra que estás buscando.

Según el Diccionario de Ciencias Jurídicas, Políticas y Sociales de Manuel Ossorio, "interdicto" es un recurso judicial consistente en "un procedimiento en materia civil encaminado a obtener del juez una resolución rápida, que se dicta sin perjuicio de mejor derecho, a efectos de evitar un peligro o de reconocer un derecho posesorio." Según algunos autores, corresponde hablar de "interdicción".

En la jerga de los abogados, también se habla de "una **cautelar**", omitiendo el sustantivo "medida", ej. *Le dictaron una cautelar* (también una sola palabra).

Acabo de recordar que un término que se usa mucho, al menos en nuestro medio, es "**perimetral**". He aquí la definición:

"Una “perimetral” u orden de alejamiento es una medida cautelar dispuesta por una autoridad judicial ante una denuncia de una persona que siente amenazada su seguridad e integridad, mediante la cual se le prohíbe al agresor residir o acudir al lugar donde hubiera cometido un delito o donde tuviera residencia la víctima." ([Fuente](https://desdematanza.com.ar/sociedad/violencia-de-genero-perimetral/#:%7E:text=Una%20%E2%80%9Cperimetral%E2%80%9D%20u%20orden%20de,donde%20tuviera%20residencia%20la%20v%C3%ADctima.))

Comment: No, ninguna de éstas es la que recurdo que se usaba ... Lo de "una cautelar", en realidad "medida cautelar" es un término más general (la orden de alejamiento es un tipo específico de medida cautelar) ....  Claro, quizá en la jerga legal, al decir "una cautelar" se refieren específicamente a la orden de alejamiento?  En todo caso, no, sigo aún frustrado de que no logro recordar la palabrita aquella !!!!

Comment: Acabo de hacer un agregado. Tal vez sea la palabra que estás buscando.

Comment: Perimetral .... no conocía esta palabra (es decir, no la conocía con este significado — por supuesto que perímetro sí ... ).  Más y más estoy pensando que quizá fuera una palabra completamente informal, usada en "slang" (quizá exclusivamente en Venezuela?) ...  Así como por ejemplo en inglés uno ve que los criminales le tienen sus nombres informales a los "confidential informants" ("snitch", "rat", "nark")